# Google Chrome Extension Not Showing PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome-extension

I have Made a Chrome Extension Which Requires PHP

Manifest.json :

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Website Blocker",
"version": "1.0.1",
"description": "Website Blocker is an extension, Which allows you to block certain websites. It also Blocks Certain Websites based on your age. These information Will , be Sold and will be stored in a Hash Method for the best Security.",
"author": "Ryan Da Ghost",

"icons": {
    "120": "blocker.png"
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "blocker.png",
    "default_title": "Website Blocker Settings",
    "default_popup": "popup.php"
},

"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js"]
}
```

}

popup.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Website Blocker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Website Hi</h1>
  <hr />

  <span><a href="" target="_blank">It seems You haven't Logged In!</a></span>

  <?php echo "Hello world"; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

I see a returned value of NULL, I see nothing at all.
Could someone tell me what is going on?

I'd Suspect that Google Chrome / Firefox / Edge do not have a supported engine for PHP code. I would love to fix this or just see this in the background since I would need to connect to a database and get the Data from their. I could return a value and check it in JavaScript code.

Comment: Browser don't have a PHP server so this won't work.

Comment: if you need you can send ajax request to php server and get data.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language and never renders on client side.

Comment: @vimuth is correct. [Here is an article that could point you in the right direction.](https://dev.to/debosthefirst/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-that-makes-api-calls-1g04). The API you'd call wouldn't be a COVID API. In your case, it would be your PHP server.

Comment: @MsonC Great Article Tysm :)